# Confusing behavior of a BehaviorSubject in my Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I recently ran into a problem and can't really figure out what's wrong with my code at this point, hopefully someone of you can help me.

All I am trying to do is changing the value of my `BehaviorSubject` with a function but it isn't working out.

**chat.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class ChatService {
  chatId = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

  constructor() {
    this.chatId.next(1);
  }

  changeChatId(chatId: number) {
    console.log(chatId);
    this.chatId.next(chatId);
  }
}
```

So the subscribers get the default as well as the changed `chatId` from the constructor. But as soon as I try to change it with the *changeChatId* function nothing happens at all. The right id's get passed into the function I already debugged that but the line *this.chatId.next(chatId)* doesn't seem to do anything.

**ADD**

These are the other components the service is currently used in.

**chat-message-list**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { ChatService } from "../../../shared/services/chat.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat-message-list',
  templateUrl: './chat-message-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat-message-list.component.css'],
  providers: [ChatService]
})
export class ChatMessageListComponent implements OnInit {
  chatId: number;

  constructor(private chat: ChatService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.chat.chatId.subscribe(
      chatId => this.updateMessageList(chatId)
    );
  }

}
```

**chat-item**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../../../shared/models/user.model';
import { ChatService } from '../../../shared/services/chat.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat-list-item',
  templateUrl: './chat-list-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat-list-item.component.css'],
  providers: [ChatService]
})
export class ChatListItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() 
  user: User;

  constructor(private chat: ChatService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onChatItemSelected(){
    this.chat.changeChatId(this.user.id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your ChatService a singleton (shared) service. Add it to the providers of your ngModule. This allows all the components that use the ChatService to share the same service instance.

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [ChatService]
})
```

And remove it from your components providers. When you are adding it to your components providers, that component gets its own instance of ChatService which can not be used by other components.

Comment: I wasted like 3 hours on that, I immediately try that out even tho we have like 1.20am. Thank you so much for you fast answer :)